# Can I use TwitterBootstrap themes for Grails project?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I am simple project manager and trying to understand, can I use any Twitter Bootstrap theme, e.g. one of [those](http://themeforest.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=twitter+bootstrap), for Grails project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you are providing a [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/) themes. You cannot use Wordpress themes on a `Grails` application. If you want to use [Bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/) install the [Grails Bootstrap Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Bootstrap is all about looks and Grails is about functionality, no problems at all to use them both.

Comment: The question is about Bootstrap Wordpress Theme and your answer is then not correct.